# How to find Kolmogorov Forward Equations, given generator matrix Q?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

I am having difficulty in forming Kolmogorov Forward Equations. I understand how the KFE is derived and that $$\frac {d}{ds} p_{ij} (s) = \sum_{k \neq j} p_{ik} (s) \lambda_{k} r_{kj} - p_{ij} (s)\lambda_j $$ is the formula to be used [i.e., $ P'(s) = P(s)Q $] but I don't understand how to *form* the KFEs for particular scenarios in the first place using these formulae. For example, could you please take me through the process involved in forming the KFE for a continuous time Markov chain with generator matrix as follows (I believe having the generator matrix, Q is sufficient to finding the KFE): 
$$
     Q=   \begin{pmatrix}
        -0.1 & 0.1 & 0 \\
        0 & -0.08 & 0.08 \\
        0 & 0.2 & -0.2 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

and state space, $S = \{0,1,2\}$ Once I know how to form the KFE, I believe solving it wouldn't be especially difficult.

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, just a notation issue. Say $q_{ij}$ is the general element in matrix $Q$, and that, $\lambda_j$ is the rate of transition out of state $j$, as you seem to have. Then the KFEs can be written as:

\begin{align}
p_{ij}^{'}(s) &= \sum_{k\neq j} q_{kj}p_{ik}(s) - \lambda_j p_{ij}(s). \\
\end{align}

In the example, we have:

\begin{align}
\lambda_0 &= 0.1 \\
\lambda_1 &= 0.08 \\
\lambda_2 &= 0.2. \\
\end{align}

The specific KFEs for the first row ($i=0$) are:

\begin{align}
p_{00}^{'}(s) &= q_{10}p_{01}(s) + q_{20}p_{02}(s) - \lambda_0 p_{00}(s) \\
&= -0.1 p_{00}(s) \\
& \\
p_{01}^{'}(s) &= q_{01}p_{00}(s) + q_{21}p_{02}(s) - \lambda_1 p_{01}(s) \\
&= 0.1 p_{00}(s) + 0.2 p_{02}(s) - 0.08 p_{01}(s) \\
& \\
p_{02}^{'}(s) &= q_{02}p_{00}(s) + q_{12}p_{01}(s) - \lambda_2 p_{02}(s) \\
&= 0.08 p_{01}(s) - 0.2 p_{02}(s).
\end{align}

The first equation is easily solved. The other two in turn can be solved using:

$$p_{00}(s) + p_{01}(s) + p_{02}(s) = 1\quad\forall\; s\geq 0.$$

The KFEs for remaining rows (for $i=1,2$) are done similarly.